# How much time forge take to update composer.json after git push

Tags: git, laravel, forge

I have pushed only composer.json to update/upload package, But it seems that its not updated in vendor folder.

so my question is that , How much time forge take to update composer.json after git push. I am working in laravel.

I have created on route to check folders exist in vendor and not found newly updated package (**dompdf**) here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once deployed, the changes should be done immediately. I suggest you have a look at your latest deployment logs within the forge website.
Also have a look at your deploy script itself, maybe composer install is missing.